# How to disable hidden startups?

Tags: xubuntu, firefox, xfce, startup

When I was restarting Xubuntu, the firefox was started at startup.

But when I was going to Session and Startup, firefox is not there!

And here is the `ls /etc/xdg/autostart/` output :

```
at-spi-dbus-bus.desktop            onboard-autostart.desktop
baloo_file.desktop                 pam_kwallet_init.desktop
blueman.desktop                    plasmashell.desktop
gnome-keyring-pkcs11.desktop       polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1.desktop
gnome-keyring-secrets.desktop      polkit-kde-authentication-agent-1.desktop
gnome-keyring-ssh.desktop          powerdevil.desktop
gnome-software-service.desktop     print-applet.desktop
gsettings-data-convert.desktop     pulseaudio.desktop
indicator-application.desktop      update-notifier.desktop
indicator-messages.desktop         user-dirs-update-gtk.desktop
indicator-sound.desktop            xembedsniproxy.desktop
kdeconnectd.desktop                xfce4-clipman-plugin-autostart.desktop
klipper.desktop                    xfce4-notes-autostart.desktop
krunner.desktop                    xfce4-power-manager.desktop
light-locker.desktop               xfce4-volumed.desktop
nautilus-autostart.desktop         xfsettingsd.desktop
nm-applet.desktop                  xscreensaver.desktop
nvidia-settings-autostart.desktop
```

Update: I was trying this command later but firefox not apeared :

```
cd /etc/xdg/autostart/ && sudo sed --in-place 's/NoDisplay=true/NoDisplay=false/g' *.desktop
```

And here is the question, how can I disable firefox from startup?

Comment: Did you run `cd /etc/xdg/autostart/` before `sudo sed --in-place 's/NoDisplay=true/NoDisplay=false/g' *.desktop`?

Comment: @ M.Becerra yes I was run that code before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The another location that cause to startup applications is `~/.config/autostart`

In that location I have firefox.desktop and after remove that file my problem was solved.

```
rm ~/.config/autostart/firefox.desktop
```